# CSS only way to make some div sticky

Tags: html, css

I need to create a page that looks like this wireframe:

[image]

The two sections need to be in the center of the page because they have fixed widths and the right section needs to stay where it is. I tried using `position: sticky` by wrapping the two divs to a container and made the container scrollable, and it works as intended, but only if my cursor in within the boundary of the blue box. Is it possible to make the right section sticky without resorting to JS?

Here's a snippet of the code:

```css
.container {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
display: flex;
height: 100vh;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scrollable {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 300px;
}

.sticky {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 100px;
position: sticky;
position: -webkit-sticky;
top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="scrollable">Scrollable content</div>
<div class="sticky">Sticky content</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make the container full width then, instead of only as wide as those two columns demand? (And before you ask how, show a proper [mre] of what you currently have.)

Comment: @CBroe how do I center the content in the middle of the page if the container if full width? Also, added the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I figured, any container element that needs to have a box stuck over it gets a class of wireframe.

```
<div class="wireframe">…(content goes here)…</div>
```

The easy part was drawing a box around any element with that class.  I decided to use outlines, because they’re rarely employed for box edging and they don’t affect the layout even if your box-sizing is set to content-box.

```
.wireframe {outline: 2px solid gray;}

.wireframe {outline: 2px solid gray;
   background:
      linear-gradient(to top right,
         transparent 49.9%, gray 49.9%,
         gray 50.1%, transparent 50.1%);
}
```